# How do I parameterize an Activity from within AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a `CustomListActivity` which I wish to expose two facets of the same data.

For example: I have a list of cars, and would like to list the set of colors, and the set of models. These would be filtered on mimetype from my `ContentProvider`:

org.acme.cars.cursor.dir/colors
  org.acme.cars.cursor.dir/models

My `CustomListActivity` is quite involved, but general enough to be re-used, but:

- the user should be able to swap between the two lists from a menu/button bar
- the list is MAIN LAUNCHER intent.
- the user's choice of facet (model or color) should be remembered
- we should be able to call these activities via mimetype.

So, my question is:

**Can I declare two activities in the AndroidManifest.xml, each one with the same class, parameterizing it, or do I need to use some switch from within the class?**

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep it a single activity, keep the layouts in separate XML files, and use setContentView to switch between them?

Comment: This also preserves the notion of multiple views of a single model.